# Custom field disappeared from screen options

Tags: custom-field

I've been trying to display the custom field section for my posts in the admin, but it's not under screen options anymore... Was it moved somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any custom fields plugins installed, such as Advanced Custom Fields? It auto-hides the Core custom fields, but there's a filter you can use to re-enable them.

Comment: Yes, I use advanced custom fields, but it didn't hide anything untill then! What's the filter?

Comment: Well, it's a bad behavior from ACF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ACF installed, they added a setting to disable Core's Custom Fields to try to speed up editor page load time. To disable you can use this filter:

```
add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');
```